# Facebook Business Accounts for managing/developing applications

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-developers

As described at [What is the difference between a business account and a personal account?](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=131976240210052#What-is-the-difference-between-a-business-account-and-a-personal-account?)

> Business accounts are designed for individuals who only want to use the site to administer Pages and their ad campaigns. For this reason, business accounts do not have the same functionality as personal accounts. Business accounts have limited access to information on the site. [...]  In addition, business accounts cannot be found in search, send or receive friend requests, or create/develop apps.

It's understood that in order to create and manage applications one needs a personal account. Under which account should the apps go if the owner of the applications wants to represent themselves as a business identity for example a LLC?

The current thinking would be to assign an employee with administrative rights within the company as the "administrator" in the roles in application settings. Then any contractor, developer, person outsourced can be assigned to a developer role.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity/

Though the "administrator" still ends up being a person and as such when this individual leaves the company the credentials would need to be handed it over leading to having to add this to the contract itself

> Please give access to Mr.NewGuyTakingYourJob and remove yourself as administrator from all our applications, thank you.

Ok, problem solved but then the cycle repeats itself when Mr.NewGuyTakingYourJob decides to quit or go AWOL.

*How does one manage Facebook applications under the business identity of, for example a LLC?*

Comment: http://masterful-marketing.com/facebook-business-accounts/#axzz2TqGEiohM some discussion regarding it i recently crossed over it

Answer (score 1):

From a technological perspective, the important problem which you are addressing -- that of a disgruntled admin "hijacking" a Facebook application -- does not seem to currently have a solution.

This problem is virtually identical to that of a Facebook page being similarly hijacked, and as mentioned in [this article on Mashable](http://mashable.com/2011/09/05/facebook-flaw-hijack-page/) from  Sept. 2011, the latter seems to be a flaw in Facebook's security architecture.  Judging from the articles found in a Google search today for "hijack facebook page disgruntled employee", it would seem that this flaw has not yet been fixed.

Moreover, technologically, this danger exists regardless of the legal nature of the business entity involved.  So, I don't think that the perspective of an LLC changes anything.

From your description of the "repeating cycle," I suspect that you were not asking for a legal perspective on how to prevent or manage this problem, say, via clauses in contracts ... etc.